# Python - Ctypes: How to pass Void* as argument

Tags: python, ctypes

I have to use 2 functions from a DLL in CTypes. Those functions have a `void*` as argument. But whatever I try, I can't make it work. I get an error telling me that I use the wrong type. I have looked on many posts and read the doc, but I can't figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Python 2.7 on windows.

My C functions are:

```
void WriteRam(unsigned address, unsigned length, void* buffer)
void ReadRam(unsigned address, unsigned length, void* buffer)
```

In Python, I'm trying to pass a list to the functions, like this:

```
audioVolume = 32767
for i in range(buffSize):
    txBuff.append(int(audioVolume * math.sin(i)) )
WriteRam(0, 64, txBuff)
```

My Python functions are:

```
WriteRam = DPxDll['DPxWriteRam']
def DPxWriteRam(address=None, length=None, buffer=None):
    #test = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(buffer) # not working
    #p_buffer = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.c_void_p) # not working
    p_buffer = ctypes.cast(ctypes.py_object(buffer), ctypes.c_void_p) # not working
    #p_buffer = ctypes.c_void_p() # not working
    WriteRam.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_void_p] 
    WriteRam(address, length, ctypes.byref(p_buffer))
```

Comment: What is `txBuff`? I would expect `buf=ctypes.c_void_p(); WriteRam(address, length, buf)` to work.

Comment: It makes no sense to pass the function a pointer to a list object. A `PyListObject` has the list's reference count, type, length, a pointer to the array of Python objects, and the allocated size of the array. What's the audio format? That determines the type of the buffer and length in bytes (e.g. an array of `c_char`, `c_short`, etc).

Comment: It looks like by having ctypes.byref(p_buffer) you make reference to a reference (void**) instead of void*.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that txBuff is a list of integer (but can be char). As for the type of the buffer, it can be c_char or c_short. The C functions can't be changed.

Comment: Aya's answer should solve your problem, assuming you modify it for the type of array you need. Based on the range of +/- 32767, I'd guess it's `c_int16`. That's common for audio.

Comment: Now I realllly feel stupid, but I get the error "an integer is required" on "packed_data = (ctypes.c_int * item_count)(int_list)". I must say that I don't understand that line, or rather the (int_list).

Comment: @BaldDude Sorry. That should've been `packed_data = (ctypes.c_int * item_count)(*int_list)` like the example just below, but it looks like eryksun corrected it for me. FWIW, `ctypes.c_int * item_count` returns a constructor for an `int` array of length `item_count`, and the `*int_list` calls it with the contents of `int_list`. It's equivalent to `apply(ctypes.c_int * item_count, int_list)` if you're familiar with `apply()`, but that's been deprecated since v2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `txBuff` is a list of integers, then you'll need to pack them into an array. The following code ought to work, but I can't test it...

```
def DPxWriteRam(address, int_list):
    int_size = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)
    item_count = len(int_list)
    total_size = int_size * item_count
    packed_data = (ctypes.c_int * item_count)(*int_list)
    WriteRam(ctypes.c_uint(address), ctypes.c_uint(total_size), packed_data)

DPxWriteRam(whatever, [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

...although if `WriteRam` is pretty much just doing a `memcpy()`, then you could just use this...

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL('msvcrt.dll')

def DPxWriteRam(address, int_list):
    int_size = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)
    item_count = len(int_list)
    total_size = int_size * item_count
    packed_data = (ctypes.c_int * item_count)(*int_list)
    libc.memcpy(address, packed_data, total_size)
```

...which I *can* test...

```
>>> l = range(4)
>>> p = libc.malloc(1000)
>>> DPxWriteRam(p, l)
>>> s = ' ' * 16
>>> libc.memcpy(s, p, 16)
>>> print repr(s)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: As a "great man" once said: Dooooh!!! (my bad)
Tested it, works great!! 
Thank you guys you made my day.